# Scripting IIS7 configuration for ISAPI DLL

Tags: iis, iis-7, isapi

First, I'll humbly admit that A.) I'm a programmer and B.) I'm asking this for someone else so I have almost no first hand experience with what I'm asking.

We would like to be able to write an installer to configure and start IIS 7 (if not already started), as well as load a custom programmed DLL.  It takes following some [fairly arduous instructions](http://chee-yang.blogspot.com/2009/10/configure-windows-7-iis7-for-isapi-dll.html) to just do it on one computer.

What we need to be able to do is script this installation, could someone point us in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is

1. Prepare an [unattended installation of IIS7.0](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/133/using-unattended-setup-to-install-iis/) (only add the components you need)
2. Use either [appCmd](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/114/getting-started-with-appcmdexe/) or the IIS 7 [powershell snap-in](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/447/managing-iis-with-the-iis-powershell-snap-in/) to create the vDirs and configure the handler mappings

Execute from a vbscript or batch